# SQLSTATE[23000] error: Magento OneStepCheckout while upgrading

Tags: magento, innodb, checkout, magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

After upgrading my Magento installation from 1.3.2.1 to 1.7.0.2 I get the following error when I place an order (using OneStepCheckout).

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_new`.`sales_order_tax_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_TAX_ITEM_TAX_ID_SALES_ORDER_TAX_TAX_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`tax_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order_tax` (`tax_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UP)
```

Is there anybody with a quick fix?
 It's the last thing that blocks the whole update process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this .
[This can give you hint to solve it out.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/265847/)